# android.widget.LinearLayout instance leaking

Tags: android, android-activity, memory-leaks, leakcanary

I have two activities, QuestionnaireSelectionActivity and QuestionnaireMainActivity. QuestionnaireMainActivity is started with an intent by QuestionnaireSelectionActivity. QuestionnaireMainActivity shows a succession of fragments.

When I try to go back to QuestionnaireSelectionActivity from QuestionnaireMainActivity by pressing the back button LeakCanary reports a leak.

None of these two activities references the other in any way (other than the intent). I set all references to views etc to null when the fragment is destroyed and there are no inner classes.

QuestionnaireSelectionActivity does have a LinearLayout but I don't understand how it can be involved in this problem. Ihaven't referenced any LinearLayout in my code.

Could anyone please help me understand how my activity is leaking?

Below is the report from LeakCanary:

```
│ GC Root: System class
│
├─ android.view.WindowManagerGlobal class
│    Leaking: NO (a class is never leaking)
│    ↓ static WindowManagerGlobal.sDefaultWindowManager
│                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
├─ android.view.WindowManagerGlobal instance
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    ↓ WindowManagerGlobal.mViews
│                          ~~~~~~
├─ java.util.ArrayList instance
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    ↓ ArrayList.elementData
│                ~~~~~~~~~~~
├─ java.lang.Object[] array
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    ↓ Object[].[2]
│               ~~~
├─ android.widget.LinearLayout instance
│    Leaking: YES (View.mContext references a destroyed activity)
│    mContext instance of com.android.neptune.QuestionnaireMainActivity with mDestroyed = true
│    View#mParent is set
│    View#mAttachInfo is not null (view attached)
│    View.mWindowAttachCount = 1
│    ↓ LinearLayout.mContext
╰→ com.android.nq.QuestionnaireMainActivity instance
​     Leaking: YES (ObjectWatcher was watching this because com.android.nq.QuestionnaireMainActivity received Activity#onDestroy() callback and Activity#mDestroyed is true)
​     key = c4204b14-4279-44d3-ba57-83e5cb26a1ef
​     watchDurationMillis = 5185
​     retainedDurationMillis = 183
```

Answer (score 0):

This leaks look similar to the one identified here: https://github.com/square/leakcanary/blob/1f6c971caba4d5cf78ac561b0cec006a2c482a1b/shark-android/src/main/java/shark/AndroidReferenceMatchers.kt#L673

It looks like the Android WindowManagerGlobal singleton is keeping a reference to your LinearLayout instance after the activity has been destroyed, though it's not clear why.

This is most likely not a bug in your app, though it's probably triggered by a behavior specific to your app.

Can you create a new issue in LeakCanary? https://github.com/square/leakcanary/issues If you provide the Android versions on which you're seeing this as well as a hprof file (that's helps a ton) then we can investigate and maybe identify the exact issue in the Android framework.

Comment: Hi, i experienced this as well, the difference is it occurs during screen rotation. Is this false positive?